# How to parse strings containing ampersands with NSXMLParser?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

The input string is

```
<path>a &amp; b</path>
```

and my Objective C parser code is

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    ...
    if(parserState==EXPECT_PATH) {
        NSLog(@"got %@", string);
    }
    ...
}
```

This prints `got a` instead of `got a &amp; b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parser:foundCharacters:` can be called multiple times for one element's contents. It is your responsibility to append all characters from multiple runs of the method to one string.

So unless you can confirm that `parser:foundCharacters:` doesn't get called again right after the first run, this is expected behavior.

Comment: +1 Yes, I was resetting `parserState` on the first call. Avoiding that solved the problem.