# Parsing XML, single quote character in content, ios5

Tags: ios5, nsxmlparser

I 'm developing an rss reader and everything works fine except when there is a character like (') in the content of the element I 'm getting.
I guess I should use some kind of string function that replaces or changes somehow the escape characters...

for example if in the xml i have :

```
<desciption>this is John's newspaper</description>
```

I don't get "this is John's newspaper" but "s newspaper"

here is my code :

```
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    rssFeeds            = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url          = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData  *data       = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    xmlParser           = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];
    return self;
}


- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        currentFeed = [rssReader alloc];
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
    {
        currentFeed.rssTitle = str1;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"description"])
    {
        currentFeed.rssDescription = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
    {
        currentFeed.rsspubDate = currentNodeContent;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        [rssFeeds addObject:currentFeed];
        currentFeed = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[xmlParser rssFeeds] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    INrssCell *cell = (INrssCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ingrCell"];
    rssReader *currectFeed = [xmlParser.rssFeeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLbl.text = currectFeed.rssTitle;
    cell.dateLbl.text = currectFeed.rsspubDate;
    cell.descLbl.text = currectFeed.rssDescription;
    return cell;
}
```

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

XML requires certain characters to be escaped.
For example, you couldn't put a '>' character in or it would confuse the parser.

You see examples of this in HTML.
The escaped character you're looking for is:

```
&rsquo;
```

You need to replace the ' characters in your XML.

```
<description>this is John&rsquo;s newspaper</description>
```

Source:
http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html

I suggest going through the list and ensuring none of the listed characters appear in your XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url 
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                 error:nil];

// You can pre-process(replace certain characters, ...) content of xml in here.

NSData* data = [contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Edit: Check out the answer in this question [How to parse strings containing ampersands with NSXMLParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838708/how-to-parse-strings-containing-ampersands-with-nsxmlparser)